# how to show suggestions and Cancellation errors that shows when change my sql version to 8.0.25 in phpmyadmin wamp server?

Tags: phpmyadmin

i upgraded MY SQL version from 5.7.31 to 8.0.25 in wamp server, and i'm using queries that released in the new version 8.0 such as (Window Function Concepts and Syntax), and queries run very well with output,

but the problem is:

- in phpMyadmin in wamp server when write SQL queries related with the new version 8.0, it shows errors in syntax, although queries work well !

[image]

- when i write query for example (CREATE DATABASE), there are suggestions show like in image i attached, but when i write SQL queries related with the new version 8.0 like (OVER(), PRECEDING) in the SQL box, there are no any suggestions to this queries!

[image]

could you help me

Comment: It seems you are using a phpmyadmin version that is not ready for mysql v8. Upgrade it.

Comment: How to upgrade it please

Comment: Check out its manual, it has a section on upgrading.

Comment: i updated phpmyadmin version to 5.1.0, but the same problem

Comment: Then phpmyadmin does not support these syntaxes yet. It happens. But this does not affect your queries. Please remember, phpmyadmin is not a developer tool, it is a database admin tool.